# ¿Cómo dibujar "X" con array simple y sin usar ||?

Tags: java

Estoy intentando imprimir una "X" por pantalla a la cual se le de un número y me dibuje una "X" según el numero asignado ejemplo:

```
n= 5 

X___X 
_X_X_ 
__X__ 
_X_X_ 
X___X 

n=6

X____X 
_X__X_ 
__XX__ 
__XX__ 
_X__X_ 
X____X
```

y he encontrado por ahi varios ejemplos de los cuales me guie para hacer esto

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingresa tamaño de la X:");
        int tamano=input.nextInt();

        if (tamano == 0)
            System.out.println("ERROR");
        else
        {
            String[][]dibujo = new String[tamano][tamano];

            for ( int i=0; i < dibujo.length ;i++){
                for (int j=0;  j<dibujo.length;j++){
                    int x = i +1;
                    if((i==j)  ||  (j == (tamano - x))){
                        dibujo[i][j] = "X";
                        System.out.print(dibujo[i][j] + " ");
                    }
                    else{
                       dibujo[i][j] = "_";
                       System.out.print(dibujo[i][j] + " ");
                    }
                }  
                System.out.println();
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

El problema es que requiero realizar este patrón en un Pseudolenguaje el cual no me esta permitiendo usar el || (distinto), según ese lenguaje tiene un <> pero me lanza error booleano, ademas de que tampoco me permite usar arreglos multidimensionales, por eso quería preguntarles, como podría realizar esa "X" sin necesidad de usar arreglos simples y sin el "distinto a".

Muchas gracias.

Comment: La operación booleana || no es "distinto", es la OR, la operacion "distinto" es !=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te planteo una solucion distinta. La explicacion es la siguiente:

una vez que sabemos el numero que te han indicado por teclado, (yo lo he llamado `tam`) vamos a hacer dos bucles. el primero para recorrer filas y el segundo para recorrer columnas. la cuestion va a estar en el bucle exterior:

primero asignamos TODOS los caracteres como `_`:

```
  dibujo[i][j] = "_";
```

ahi acabamos el bucle interior.

Despues, el indice del bucle exterior nos esta indicando donde hay que poner las X. En este caso son 2. Una en el valor de la I, el otro en el valor de N-I-1:

```
  dibujo[i][i] = "X";
  dibujo[i][tam - i - 1] = "X";
```

y por ultimo, finalizamos el bucle.

El algoritmo al completo seria:

```
for ( int i=0; i < tam ;i++){
  for (int j=0;  j<tam;j++){
    dibujo[x][i] = "_";
  }
  dibujo[i][tam - i - 1] = "X";
  dibujo[i][i] = "X";  
}
```

con esto tendrias asignado en `dibujo` los caracteres de tu letra. Ahora te falta imprimirlo, volvemos a utilizar los bucles de antes:

```
 for ( int i=0; i < tam ;i++){
  for (int j=0;  j<tam;j++){
    System.out.print(dibujo[x][i]);
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Jakala, es justamente lo que necesitaba, no habia caso de poder hacer funcionar mi codigo, pero con tu explicacion ya lo vi mas claro, estuve varias horas buscando reemplazar el uso del OR ya que donde lo necesitaba implementar no me funcionaba, pero ahora se me hizo mas facil aplicarlo.
Saludos!!!

Answer (score 1):

esta podria ser un solución sin arreglos, este simbolo en Java es para || or

```
public class MyClass {
    static int n=6;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        int cola=n;
        int punta=0;
        for ( int i=0; i < n ;i++){
            for (int j=0;  j<n;j++){
              if(j==cola-1 || j==punta) 
              {System.out.print('X');}
              else
              {System.out.print('_');}
            }
            System.out.println();
            cola--;
            punta++;
          }
    }
}
```

puedes probarlo en https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler/

Answer (score 1):

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DibujandoUnTache {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;
        n = teclado.nextInt();

        String [][] matriz = new String [n][n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (i == j) {
                    matriz[i][j] = "@" ;
                }else {
                    matriz[i][j] =  " ";
                }
            }
            
        }

        
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            matriz[i][n - 1-i] = "@";
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                System.out.print(matriz[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Esta seria mi solucion

Comment: Intenta dar una explicación de porque falla el código de la pregunta y que has hecho tú para solucionarlo, no pongas código sin explicación

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
    int n = 5;

    int y = (n - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if ((i == j) || ((i + j) == y)) {
                System.out.print("X");
            } else {
                System.out.print("_");
            }

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).